# Sum of powers is a perfect square

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, square-numbers

Show that $ \sum_{k=1}^{2000} {2^k+7^k+9^k}$ îs a perfect square.
I tried grouping terms or evaluating the geometric progressions...but without success. I got 
$$\frac{48∗2^{2000}+28∗7^{2000}+27∗9^{2000}−271}{24}$$with the formula of a geometric sum. How do i show this îs a square?

Comment: Hint : Add the three geometric series

Comment: $\frac{48*2^{2000}+28*7^{2000}+27*9^{2000}-271}{24}$ how do i show this îs a square?

Comment: In light of @JyrkiLahtonen's answer, it's worth wondering whether it should be$$\sum_{k=\color{limegreen}{0}}^{2000}(2^k+7^k+9^k)=\frac{2^{2005}\times3^2+2^3\times3\times7^{2001}+2\times3^{4004}-2\times3\times31}{12^2},$$but that doesn't look liable to have a simple proof of being a square.

Comment: Amarius, I included your calculation in the question body. Please do that yourself in the future. That way all passers-by will see what you have tried.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the sums $S(q):=\sum_{k=1}^{2000}q^k$, $q=2,7,9$, modulo four.

With $q=2$ that sum is even but not a multiple of four, all due to the first term. With $q=9$ all the terms are congruent to $1\pmod4$. As $4\mid 2000$ we also have $4\mid S(9)$. With $q=7$ we see that the residues of the terms modulo four alternate between $+1$ and $-1$. Again implying that $4\mid S(7)$.

The conclusion is that $S(2)+S(7)+S(9)$ is even but not a multiple of four. Therefore it is NOT a square.

Comment: Initially I carelessly started the summation with $k=0$. In that case Little Fermat modulo five showed that $S(2)\equiv S(7)\equiv S(9)\equiv1\pmod5$, implying that the last digit of $S(2)+S(7)+S(9)$ is a three - again impossible for a square. I apologize for any lingering confusion caused by that sum appearing in earlier versions of my answer.